# Esper last inserted Event

Tags: java, rule-engine, esper

Is there a way to get the last inserted event in esper core prior to rule completion?

```
Configuration cepConfig = new Configuration();
     cepConfig.getEngineDefaults().getMetricsReporting().
     setEnableMetricsReporting(true);
cepConfig.addEventType("Stream", Stream.class.getName());
EPServiceProvider cep = EPServiceProviderManager.getProvider("myCEPEngine", cepConfig);
EPRuntime cepRT = cep.getEPRuntime();
EPAdministrator cepAdm = cep.getEPAdministrator();
EPStatement cepStatement = cepAdm.createEPL("select * from Stream.win:length(100)") ;
cepStatement.addListener(new CEPListener());
```

Now for event insertion i am using this sample code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
     GenerateRandomStream(cepRT);
     //Here I want get the last inserted event
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: were you able to try the approach outlined in my answer? results?

Comment: i was unable to utilize the below mentioned thing...

Answer (score 0):

There is a "prev" function that you could use.
What specifically do you mean with "prior to rule completion"?

Comment: by saying prior to rule completion, i mean prior to *listener*.. I want to know whether there is any other way to get that information, *not using listener*, may be using the esper client package.

Answer (score 0):

Use the on demand query api to make a one time query of the esper runtime engine:

```
String query = "select prev(0, evt) from Stream.win:length(10) as evt";
EPOnDemandQueryResult result = cepRT.executeQuery(query);
```